# How do I return variables from a view and have that output either a template or raw JSON based on context?

Tags: django, json, django-templates, django-views

I don't have a specific need to do this at the moment. I'm just curious what would be the best way to make it so that:

example.com/cars/honda/ -- Would perhaps return a car template page with pics and info about Hondas
example.com/cars/honda.json -- Would return a JSON object with Honda info

Any ideas?

Comment: what's your definition of "the best way"?  based on what criteria?  There is already a straight forward way of mapping those uris to view functions (in urls.py) and returning the data you need.  Why isn't that acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, with RESTful APIs, this sort of thing is handled with [content type negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation). I haven't used it, but [Django REST framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) can provide content negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a single function responsible for collating the info, and then two separate views responsible for calling the common function and either rendering a template or encoding as JSON.